# DecimalFormat throws null pointer exception because of a dot

Tags: java

So we have a double price which we want to cut off a few of the decimals so we created this method:

```
    public static double roundDoubleToTwoDecimalPoints(double value) {
    DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat(",##");
    return Double.parseDouble(df2.format(value));

}
```

Which we then use in our getter for the price

```
    public double getPriceLine() {
    return LogicFacade.roundDoubleToTwoDecimalPoints(this.priceLine = this.price * this.qty);
}
```

So the problem is for me it doesnt work when the DecimalFormat is set with a .## it throws a nullpointer exception saying it read a comma so it cant use the method. I changed it to a comma and it no longer throws me a nullpointer exception but now it doesnt give me the actual priceLine but just a "random" double

Our teacher told us it was because it was created on a different computer with the language set to another than mine. Regardless I hope some of you can give some help :)

Comment: Try using `DecimalFormat df2 = DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.US); df2.applyPattern(".##");` to force the locale to one where `.` is the decimal and `,` is just a thousands separator.

Comment: DecimalFormat df2 = DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);  

It says NumberFormat can not be converted to DecimalFormat

Comment: You may need to explicitly cast `.getInstance(...)` to `DecimalFormat`

Comment: It says the same thing :(

Comment: you receive a `double` and return a `double` and both have same format. If you want to print its value with `,` or `.` you can use a String instead